# Selenium : wrong method when I launch the program (find_element problem)

Tags: selenium, methods

I've just begun to use the library Selenium for my school Python project. 
Here is my problem : in my program, I try to find all the elements with a specific class thanks to the command `find_element_by_class_name`. Here is how my program is written :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.mywebsite.com')
list_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ui header')
```

However, when I launch the program, I get an error telling me it can't find such elements `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ui header"}`
Well, that's kind of normal I guess because it uses the css selector method instead of searching elements by their class name.

Does anyone know where the problem comes from ?

Thank you !\

Edit : `list_elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui header')` -> `list_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ui header')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spaces with class names doesn't work here because of how the `class_name` code works. Instead try

```
list_elements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui.header')
```

Also, since your variable is called `list_elements`, did you maybe want to use a `find_elements` function for this variable?